# Gambler's Ruin Markov Chain for specific question

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, gambling

Jill has 20 dollars in her pocket. She goes to the Crown Casino in Melbourne and gambles. She would get 10 dollars if she won and would lose 10 dollars if she lost. She would win the game if she got 50 dollars or end if she went broke. She wins a game with probability $p$ and loses with probability $1-p$.

a) what is the probability that she wins the game in three turns

b)if the probability of the game ending is $q$ for a game to end. And if she ends the game in 5 turns then $q_5=1$ for n ∈ {1,2,3,4} prove that $q_n=pq_{n+1} +(1-p)q_{n-1}$ for $n$ ∈ $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$

c)if the difference between $q_{n+1}$, $q_n$ is $d_n$, then $d_{n-1} =\alpha d_n.$ what is the value of $α$.

I think the answer for first one is $p^3$. 
I have no clue for b and c parts. Any help is appreciated

For b n c part do I have to make use of the Random Walk strategy?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I could write down the state transition diagram and matrix. But the expression to be proven have proved to be hard to make out

Comment: You think the answer to the first one is $p^3$? You’re not sure?

Comment: @amd I solved it using the matrices. I am ending up with $p^3$ in the last row. But I want to confirm it still

Comment: Solve it a different way to check your result, then: if she starts with \$20 and gets to \$50 in exactly three games, how many could she have lost?

Comment: I think something may have gotten lost in translation here. The recurrence in part b) suggests to me that $q_n$ is the probability of winning the game given an initial bankroll of $n\times\$10$. Also, what would $q_{-1}$ mean? This appears in the recurrence with $n=0$.

Comment: Question b is very not clear what it is asking, which affects question c. Can you please edit it so that other people can understand? Why $n \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and  $n \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: @soobster I was presented this question in the assessment. I realised they are states 0-1-2-3-4-5 for $0,$10,$20,..,$50 dollars respectively